# Proper way to put http-server into background

Tags: linux, web-server, raspbian, background-process, http-server

I'm using raspbian on a pi Zero to serve a simple static HTML page with an index.js and some styling.

I'm using the npm package `http-server` I've installed it globally.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

In the terminal **(using ssh)**, I've done `http-server &` to put the process into the background. However, I notice that the access logs still appear in the terminal.

Is this the proper way of actually putting a web server into the background?

On same note, how would someone also put a node process into the bg? I've only ever worked with PaSS where this was handled or with APache where there were `service start` commands.

**Update..I'm doing this through SSH and so it is clearly not right way as process dies when I close my remote machine**

Thanks!

Comment: What software is this web server? I mean, where you got it? I can't remember a linux http server which executable binary name would be just "http-server"

Answer (score 2):

Which service manager does your OS use? If that's `systemd` (which is common nowadays, Raspberry Pi OS uses it), you should to have a unit file for that service, either supplied with the package or created manually. Then, use generic

```
service start <name>
```

should be mapped to more general

```
systemctl start unit-name.service
```

where `unit-name.service` is the name of the unit file in the `/etc/systemd/system` or `/lib/systemd/system`. Also,

```
systemctl enable unit-name.service
```

will configure its automatic start when machine boots.

If you don't have a unit file, refer to systemd manual on how to create it (it's easy). If your system doesn't use systemd, refer to its documentation.

---

For one-time startups, also, `nohup`, `screen` or `tmux` programs may be used to decouple a process from the tty. If you need it to start automatically, this is not the correct way.